# VBA: Curiously slow macro for cross-sheet operation (taking 15mins for 7k rows!)

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with two sheets, namely; `Material Sheet` and `Resultant Sheet`, where the latter is an empty sheet for results. In `Material Sheet` I have material information along with the movement codes. As for the schema:

`columnA has MaterialCodes & columnG has MovementCodes`

Now, for each material there may be multiple rows with differnet movement codes from the movement-codes-set(101,102,201,202,241,242,261,262,561). I need to check the apply the following logic:

> copy all rows of a material from `Material Sheet` and paste in
>   Resultant Sheet`,
>   if (count-of-202-for-this-material >= count-of-201-for-this-material) And (count-of-242-for-this-material >= count-of-241-for-this-material) And (count-of-262-for-this-material >= count-of-261-for-this-material)

At the moment, I have the following code (end of post). During the process, it filters the valid material codes and store these codes in Resultant Sheet (not the entire row yet!)

What I want:

1. I need to modify it so all the entire_rows against each filtered material should be copied in Resultant Sheet.
2. The existing code takes too much (like 15 minutes) execution time for ~7000 values. EXTEREMELY SLOW!

FilterWRTMovement is the main driver routine. It calls collectUniqueMaterials function to collect the unique materials from columnA to collectionUniqueMaterials array. Then, for each unique material it gathers the movement codes form column-g of Material Sheet and checks the aforementioned logic in FilterValues function.

```
Sub FilterWRTMovement()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim collectionUniqueMaterials() As String
    Dim LRow As Long, counter1 As Long, counter2 As Long
        Dim result(10000) As String, movementOfOneMaterial() As String, current As String
    Dim has202 As Boolean, has242 As Boolean, has262 As Boolean
    Dim Destination As Worksheet

    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
    c = collectUniqueMaterials(collectionUniqueMaterials, LRow)
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    Set Destination = Worksheets("Resultant Sheet")

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Sheet").Range("A2:A" & LRow)
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        For Each i In collectionUniqueMaterials
            i = Trim(i)
            ReDim movementOfOneMaterial(200) As String
            has202 = True
            has242 = True
            has262 = True
            counter1 = 0

            For j = 1 To .Rows.Count
                current = Trim(Cells(j, 1))
                If current = i Then
                    movementOfOneMaterial(counter1) = Cells(j, 7)
                    counter1 = counter1 + 1
                End If
            Next j

            FilterValues movementOfOneMaterial, has202, has242, has262
            If has202 = True And has242 = True And has262 = True Then
                result(counter2) = i
                counter2 = counter2 + 1
            End If
            Erase movementOfOneMaterial
        Next i
    End With
    Destination.Range("A1").Resize(10000, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(result)

    'For Each tup In result
    'FindMe (tup)
    'Next tup
End Sub

Function collectUniqueMaterials(ByRef collection() As String, ByRef last As Long)
    Dim tmp As String

    myselect = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Sheet").Range("A2:A" & last)
    For Each cell In myselect
        If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
            tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
        End If
    Next cell

    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
    collection = Split(tmp, "|")
End Function



Function FilterValues(ByRef sarrCodes() As String, ByRef has202 As Boolean, ByRef has242 As Boolean, ByRef has262 As Boolean)
    Dim a As Long
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim objDic As Object


    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For a = LBound(sarrCodes) To UBound(sarrCodes)
        If objDic.Exists(sarrCodes(a)) Then
            objDic.Item(sarrCodes(a)) = objDic.Item(sarrCodes(a)) + 1
        Else
            objDic.Add sarrCodes(a), 1
        End If
    Next a

    If objDic.Exists("201") And objDic.Item("201") <> "" Then
        has202 = False
        If objDic.Exists("202") And objDic.Item("202") <> "" And objDic.Item("202") >= objDic.Item("201") Then
            has202 = True
        End If
    ElseIf objDic.Exists("241") And objDic.Item("241") <> "" Then
        has242 = False
        If objDic.Exists("242") And objDic.Item("242") <> "" And objDic.Item("242") >= objDic.Item("241") Then
            has242 = True
        End If
    ElseIf objDic.Exists("261") And objDic.Item("261") <> "" Then
        has262 = False
        If objDic.Exists("262") And objDic.Item("262") <> "" And objDic.Item("262") >= objDic.Item("261") Then
            has262 = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

After incorporating the suggestions from iDevelp, Issun & Nick Hebb, following code which takes 30 seconds to execute

```
Sub FilterWRTMovement()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim collectionUniqueMaterials() As String, result(10000) As String, movementOfOneMaterial() As String, current As String
    Dim LRow As Long, counter1 As Long, counter2 As Long
    Dim has202 As Boolean, has242 As Boolean, has262 As Boolean
    Dim Destination As Worksheet
    Dim materialArray As Variant, movementArray As Variant

    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
    c = collectUniqueMaterials(collectionUniqueMaterials, LRow)
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    Set Destination = Worksheets("Resultant Sheet")


    materialArray = Worksheets("Material Sheet").Range("A2:A" & LRow)
    movementArray = Worksheets("Material Sheet").Range("G2:G" & LRow)

    For Each i In collectionUniqueMaterials
        i = Trim(i)
        ReDim movementOfOneMaterial(200) As String
        has202 = True
        has242 = True
        has262 = True
        counter1 = 0

        For j = 1 To LRow - 1
            current = materialArray(j, 1)
            If current = i Then
                movementOfOneMaterial(counter1) = movementArray(j, 1)
                counter1 = counter1 + 1
            End If
        Next j

        FilterValues movementOfOneMaterial, has202, has242, has262
        If has202 = True And has242 = True And has262 = True Then
            result(counter2) = i
            counter2 = counter2 + 1
        End If
        Erase movementOfOneMaterial
    Next i
    Destination.Range("A1").Resize(10000, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(result)

    'For Each tup In result
    'FindMe (tup)
    'Next tup
End Sub
```

*Now, instead of saving the unique material codes in Resultant Sheet (`Destination.Range("A1").Resize(10000, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(result)`), what would be the optimised way to copy all the rows from "Material Sheeet" against each value of `result` array (given: for each value of result element, there are multiple rows in Material Sheet. I want all of them to get the filtered data)*

**UPDATE**
With a little tweak in Tim's post I am able to acheive the desired result in a second. Following is the VBA script:

```
Sub FilterMaterialWRTMovement()

    Const SourceSheet As String = "Material Sheet"
    Const DestinationSheet As String = "Resultant Sheet"

    Const COL_ID As Integer = 1
    Const COL_MOVE As Integer = 7

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim data As Variant, data2(), numRows As Long, numCols As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim id, mv, arrMv, pos, tmp
    Dim data2Row As Long
    Dim firstPass As Boolean

     Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        'movement codes to count
        arrMv = Array(201, 202, 241, 242, 261, 262)

        Set shtSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet)
        Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DestinationSheet)

        shtDest.Cells.Clear

        data = shtSrc.Range(shtSrc.Range("A2"), _
               shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10)).Value

        numRows = UBound(data, 1)
        numCols = UBound(data, 2)

        ReDim data2(1 To numRows, 1 To numCols)

        data2Row = 1
        firstPass = True

runAgain:
        For r = 1 To numRows
            id = data(r, COL_ID)

            If firstPass Then
                'collecting counts...
                mv = data(r, COL_MOVE)
                If Not dict.Exists(id) Then dict.Add id, Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                pos = Application.Match(mv, arrMv, 0)
                If Not IsError(pos) Then
                    tmp = dict(id)
                    If id = 7024113 Then
                    cwe = 1
                    End If
                    tmp(pos - 1) = tmp(pos - 1) + 1
                    dict(id) = tmp
                End If
                'firstPass = False
            Else
                'copying rows
                tmp = dict(id)
                If (tmp(0) <> 0) Or (tmp(2) <> 0) Or (tmp(4) <> 0) Then
                    If Not ((tmp(0) <> 0 And tmp(1) < tmp(0)) Or (tmp(2) <> 0 And tmp(3) < tmp(2)) Or (tmp(4) <> 0 And tmp(5) < tmp(4))) Then
                        For c = 1 To numCols
                            data2(data2Row, c) = data(r, c)
                        Next c
                        data2Row = data2Row + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next r

        If firstPass Then
            Beep
            firstPass = False
            GoTo runAgain
        Else
            shtDest.Cells(2, 1).Resize(numRows, numCols).Value = data2
        End If

End Sub
```

Thanks alot folks!

Comment: I dont know your "Scripting.Dictionary" thing, but wouldn't a simple VBA collection do the same job ? and faster ?

Comment: Scripting.Dictionary object is used for counting the occurence of key. Something similar to counting sort which is working just fine. But even if I comment the function call to FilterValues, I am having the same 15mins execution time! Something really wrong with "For Each i In collectionUniqueMaterials " loop struct.. is due to Redim?

Comment: Sneakyness, don't blame the code! There are far more consise and elegant ways to do this in VBA :)

Comment: My best advice is that if you are looping through actual cells, dump the data into a variant array and work with that instead. That'll save you an insane amount of time.

Comment: Your `collectUniqueMaterials` and `FilterValues` functions don't return anything... Should probably be `Sub`s instead of `Function`s.

Comment: I'm sending the values by reference.

Comment: Issun, it really helped! Thank you. Please checkout the edit and give your feedback :-)

Comment: Variants should be used and also try to use application.calculation property, I even run my macro on 40k rows and having 10k formulas but still i can finish the task in 2 to 3 seconds the reason is I use variants(suggested by issun,reafidy,jean,Jmax and also tim williams,idevlop these guys are just awsome). by the way what version are you using?

Comment: @niko, its Excel 2010 xlsm sheet.

Comment: @niko, can you elaborate how to use application.calculation in this context? Thanks for the advise though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already well-addressed, but here's another approach.  I'd be interested to try on real data if you could make it available...  In my testing: 85k rows was about 3-4sec

```
Sub FilterAndCopyRows()

Const COL_ID As Integer = 1
Const COL_MOVE As Integer = 7

Dim dict As New Scripting.dictionary
Dim data As Variant, data2(), numRows As Long, numCols As Long
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim id, mv, arrMv, pos, tmp
Dim data2Row As Long
Dim firstPass As Boolean

    'movement codes to count
    arrMv = Array(201, 202, 241, 242, 261, 262)

    Set shtSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Material Sheet")
    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resultant Sheet")

    data = shtSrc.Range(shtSrc.Range("A2"), _
           shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6)).Value

    numRows = UBound(data, 1)
    numCols = UBound(data, 2)

    ReDim data2(1 To numRows, 1 To 7)

    data2Row = 1
    firstPass = True

runAgain:
    For r = 1 To numRows
        id = data(r, COL_ID)

        If firstPass Then
            'collecting counts...
            mv = data(r, COL_MOVE)
            If Not dict.Exists(id) Then dict.Add id, Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            pos = Application.Match(mv, arrMv)
            If Not IsError(pos) Then
                tmp = dict(id)
                tmp(pos - 1) = tmp(pos - 1) + 1
                dict(id) = tmp
            End If
        Else
            'copying rows
            tmp = dict(id)
            If (tmp(1) > tmp(0)) And (tmp(3) > tmp(2)) And (tmp(5) > tmp(4)) Then
                For c = 1 To numCols
                    data2(data2Row, c) = data(r, c)
                Next c
                data2Row = data2Row + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If firstPass Then
        Beep
        firstPass = False
        GoTo runAgain
    Else
        shtDest.Cells(2, 1).Resize(numRows, numCols).Value = data2
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  Still a little room left for optimization though: the copy/don't copy test only really needs to be run once per material Id, instead of once per data row.

Comment: I have changed another change at `pos = Application.Match(mv, arrMv, 0)`. Using 0 for thrid parameter would match the exact value of the entire cell (excel's Find > "match entire cell content" option)

Comment: @vulcan- how does it run on your data?  I wasn't sure how comparable my test set was...

Comment: I have 10 columns, so to make it more general I changed the column count in data() initilization and this line ReDim data2(1 To numRows, 1 To numCols). Thank you much!

Comment: It works swiftly and perfectly fine. Your code gives has much less complexity as compared to mine. As you suggested, it can be more optimized if the entire row is copied in one iteration would make it even more fast, I'm looking into it! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Excel is it ? If 2007 or 2010, the culprit might be `For j = 1 To .Rows.Count`, working on a lot of unnecessary cells.
You could try using
 `For Each c In Range("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`
instead.

Comment: Thanks, please check the edit in the original post. Please tell me if it can be more optimized for large data.

Answer (score 1):

Two observations:

(As iDevelop mentioned) the .Rows.Count will add a lot of unnecessary overhead. Plus, isn't LRow already set to the last row number?

Also, if I'm reading the code correctly, you're adding the values to an array, then counting them in the FilterValues sub. Wouldn't it be possible to add them to a Dictionary and increment them in one pass instead of having the nested loops and making the call to FilterValues?

Comment: Thanks, please check the edit in the original post. Now both the column are copied in corresponding arrays before starting the loop. The nested loop is collecting the movement-codes for one material and the passed to FilterValues. Is there a way I can collect movement-codes from movementArray without nested loop, given the materialArray corresponds to the index of movementArray and `i` is the current material code in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

On seeing vulcan raven's comment I am posting these answer

So whenever content(s) of a cell or range of cells are changed, the formulas dependent on them and Volatile functions are recalculated. You may turn off the automatic calculation using

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'turn off the automatic calc
  'your code goes here
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'turn On the automatic calc
```

check out these links for optimization in vba

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm

and also dont use

```
if a = "" or a = "" 'thats not good way to do
```

try to use inbulit keywords `vbnullstring` and also check out these link for string optimization

http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html (suggested by brettdj).

It will give you lot of knowledge on string optimization.

Hope you learned something new today :). Thanks